# Listen to all buttons keycodes in android

Tags: android

I'm using chineese printer. It has OS android and also it has a few buttons, on of them is "scan". When I press it I don't see anything in system log. How can I find out the code of this button?

Already tried to find something in logs but didn't see anything related to this button. I even tried not my app log, but system log didn't help. I don't know if this  button  is working or not

Comment: did you tried [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ricoh.smartprint&hl=en) app?

Comment: no, i need to create my own app so i need to find out the keycode of device's "scan" button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like they used button scan instead of button "menu"
I tried this code and

```
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.e("KeyCode",keyCode+"");
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        Log.e("KeyCode",keyCode+"");
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

and i got two times

```
03-24 08:33:41.429  E/KeyCode﹕ 82
03-24 08:33:41.429  E/KeyCode﹕ 82
```

It means it has the same keycode as Menu button